Reading a CSV, modify some field values, writing it back using CsvHelper
I'm using CsvHelper v33.0.1 in a C# program. I'm taking an existing CSV file that contains 70+ columns and about 3000 rows, modifying 3 column values, then rewriting the modified rows back to the original CSV. The columns are comma delimited and values are mostly text (quoted values), but a few are numeric (int and long).
Incoming CSV:
"chgInsert","num",..."inactive","locZip","orgPhone","stmDel","stmtEmail",...
"I",12345,..."",80836,3035551234,"email","donotuse@email.com,nobody@yahoo.com",...
"I",23456....1,,80834,"","","mail","",...

Desired CSV:
"chgInsert","num",..."inactive","locZip","orgPhone","stmDel","stmtEmail",...
"U",12345,..."",80836,3035551234,"","",...

"U",23456....1,,80834,"","","","",...

Note that in the original CSV, a value can be quoted if null OR numeric if not null (inactive is an example).
The code segment below works, however I'd prefer not having to specify the column names within the code. Is there a way to have CsvHelper format the output row to match the incoming row's field value type (quoted vs. unquoted)? I had assumed ShouldQuote would do the trick, but it looks like all the columns are string type, so everything gets quoted in the modified CSV (ex. 12345 is written as "12345"). Note that csv.Parser.RawRecord shows the quoted and unquoted values, so it is possible to infer which field values are quoted or not.
  List<string> newLines = new List<string>();
  var newRecords = new List<dynamic>();

  //filePath contains the full path to the unmodified CSV file
  if (File.Exists(filePath))
  {
     var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
     {
        Delimiter = ",",
        HasHeaderRecord = true,
        ShouldQuote = args => args.FieldType == typeof(string)  //The problem is that *ALL* fields are string types, so every field is quoted
      };
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
      {
          using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
          {
             var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();
             foreach (var record in records)
             {
                // Modify 3 columns
                if (record.chgInsert.Contains("I")) record.chgInsert = "U";
                record.stmtDel = "";
                record.stmtEmail = "";
                newRecords.Add(record);
             }
          }
      }

      using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false))
      using (var cw = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
      {
          var outRecords = new List<dynamic>();

          foreach (var record in newRecords)
          {
             //Every field in record is a string type, convert some to integer (unquoted value)
             //I'd rather not hardcode the column names here, since the names may change
             // or be deleted in the future
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.num)) record.num = Convert.ToInt32(record.num);
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.inactive)) record.inactive = Convert.ToInt32(record.inactive);
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.locZip)) record.locZip = Convert.ToInt32(record.locZip);
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.orgPhone)) record.orgPhone = Convert.ToInt64(record.orgPhone);
             outRecords.Add(record);
          }
          cw.WriteRecords(outRecords);
      }
  }


This is somewhat similar to other questions where the user wanted to use "no quotes" to mean a null value and "only double qoutes" as string.Empty. How to let csvhelper distinguish null and empty string
As you said, you can get at the raw data as you are reading to see if the data is contained in quotes, but you would somehow have to save that knowledge between reading and writing. Here is an example of someone checking for quotes in a custom StringConverter https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/252#issuecomment-1924114766
Would it work if you just checked in ShouldQuote if the value was not a number?
ShouldQuote = args => !long.TryParse(args.Field, out _)


The original CSV can contain quoted numbers and we want them to remain quoted, if "123456" becomes 123456, that's undesirable. If I understand what you are saying, "123456" will not quote given the above ShouldQuote. In my code segment above, I'd like to eliminate the need to check for record.fieldName in the writer section, even moving it to the reader section if it's easier. It's that part of the code that is likely to break if the CSV columns ever change, which is why I'm looking for a cleaner way to do it based on the field values rather than the field names.

You are correct.  If a column that was supposed to be text only had the number "123456" then yes, it would be changed to 123456 without the quotes.  I have one other idea that would build off the Github comment that I'll try hopefully later when I get a chance.

How likely is it that a numeric value would be repeated in the record?
ShouldQuote = args => long.TryParse(args.Field, out _) && args.CharAt( args.IndexOf( args.Field ) - 1 ) == "\"";

That would break if args.Field is 12345 and a previous field in the same record contained the same embedded string.  Is that likely to occur?  Does the field object contain a position indicator?  If so you could use that as a parameter to IndexOf( )

Well, the current examples I have don't seem to have that situation (ex. "12345",12345) but this is production data, so I suppose anything is possible. Would the above still hold if we have 2 consecutive numbers such as 999,12345? Again, we don't have that condition now, but it could change in the future. Finally, does the above hold true if a numeric field is the first column?

I like the idea, but at this point the quotes would no longer be a part of the record. The quotes would have all been lost earlier when reading the record using. var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>(); ShouldQuote will only be hit when writing the record back to the file.

The RawRecord property has the quotes.  The Field property does not.  The CharAt should operate on the RawRecord property ... RawRecord.CharAt( RawReo
